Is it required to have the same folder structure as the Package Name in react-native android
I have seen in many react native projects MainActivity.kt file is located at the same path as the package name of app.
If the package name is "com.example.app" then MainActivity.kt file is placed at android/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/MainActivity.kt
and in some projects it is located at android/app/src/main/java/com/appName/MainActivity.kt and package name is different like com.androidexample.appname.
so if I would need to change package name then is it required to change the folder name also ?
what show be the exact path for these files.


The folder structure for MainActivity.kt (or MainActivity.java) is directly related to your app's package name. This does not apply to React-Native, but to Android architecture in general.
Correct file location:
The path to the MainActivity.kt file should match your app's package name. For example, if the package name specified in AndroidManifest.xml is com.example.app, the path to MainActivity.kt should be:
android/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/MainActivity.kt

What to change when renaming the package:
If you're changing your app's package name, you need to:

Change the package name in the following places:

In AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest package="com.newpackage.name">


In MainActivity.kt:
package com.newpackage.name




Rename the folders in your project structure to match the new package name. For example, if you're changing the package name to com.newpackage.name, the path should become:
android/app/src/main/java/com/newpackage/name/MainActivity.kt



Do you need to rename the folders?
Yes, absolutely! The folder structure must match the package name. If you don’t rename the folders, the build process will fail because Android expects the directory structure to reflect the package name.
So, if you change the package name from com.example.app to com.newpackage.name, you need to rename the folders from:
android/app/src/main/java/com/example/app/

to:
android/app/src/main/java/com/newpackage/name/

What's the easiest way to rename React-Native project?
I recommend looking at react-native-rename
npx react-native-rename@latest "new_name"


I agree @Vladlen , but as you can see in image file location is /com/autofx/ and package name is  com.autoaccessory.autofx. and this app is working as aspected and live on stores.

Android uses a mechanism to find files in the right folders and associate them with package names during the build process.
For example, the package name in AndroidManifest.xml (where the full package name com.autoaccessory.autofx is specified) and the actual package name in MainActivity.kt may differ. In Kotlin (or Java) files, the main requirement is that the package directive matches the actual file location in the file system. (package com.autofx).
This way, the app can continue to work even if the folder structure does not match the package name.
